# Can't generate TYPO3 tt_news category tree for news entry

Tags: php, typo3, tt-news, typo3-extensions

I'm using `tt_news` extension with my TYPO3 v7.6.18 (just upgraded from 6.2.31)
and I'm having problems with category tree. I did a bit more debug for `tt_news` category rendering and this is the problem so far:

the old `tca.php` looks like this:

```
'category' => Array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.category',
    'config'  => Array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'form_type'     => 'user',
        'userFunc'      => 'tx_ttnews_TCAform_selectTree->renderCategoryFields',
        'treeView'      => 1,
        'foreign_table' => 'tt_news_cat',
        'autoSizeMax'   => 50,
        'minitems'      => $confArr['requireCategories'] ? 1 : 0,
        'maxitems'      => 500,
        'MM'            => 'tt_news_cat_mm',
    ),
),
```

And this gives me wrong results, meaning, I don't get a tree, but a multi select. Now, when I change type to *user*, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\Element\UserElement::addSelectOptionsToItemArray() in /home/portal/typo3project/typo3conf/ext/tt_news/lib/class.tx_ttnews_TCAform_selectTree.php on line 167
```

I checked the line in class `tx_ttnews_TCAform_selectTree` method `renderCategoryFieldsand` and it looks like this:

```
$selItems = $fobj->addSelectOptionsToItemArray($fobj->initItemArray($this->PA['fieldConf']),$this->PA['fieldConf'],$fobj->setTSconfig($table,$row),$field);
```

The *$fobj* comes as reference in function definition: `function renderCategoryFields(&$PA, &$fobj)` and it seems, that it is somewhere defined wrong, since `addSelectOptionsToItemArray` is located in `FormEngine` and *not* `UserElement`.

Since the method is called in the tca like `tx_ttnews_TCAform_selectTree->renderCategoryFields` I can't change class, it's using.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TYPO3 7 you don't need to define a custom user function to render a list as a tree. There is a `renderType` [TCA configuration option](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#rendertype) for select-type fields, which can define tree rendering via `selectTree` value.

So the configuration should look like follows:

```
'category' => Array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:tt_news/locallang_tca.xml:tt_news.category',
    'config'  => Array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'renderType'    => 'selectTree',
        'foreign_table' => 'tt_news_cat',
        'autoSizeMax'   => 50,
        'minitems'      => $confArr['requireCategories'] ? 1 : 0,
        'maxitems'      => 500,
        'MM'            => 'tt_news_cat_mm',
        'treeConfig'    => array(
            'parentField' => 'parent_category',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Additionally you may want to play with `treeConfig` [configuration option](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#treeconfig) for some visual tuning.

Comment: In addition you may simply update `tt_news` to the latest version, because it claims to be compatible with TYPO3 7.x.

Comment: I already tried this. It produces the `#1288215890: TCA Tree configuration is invalid: "treeConfig" array is missing` error. And when I add the `'treeConfig' => array(
           'expandAll' => true,
           'parentField' => 'pid',
           'appearance' => array(
                   'showHeader' => TRUE,
           ),
   ),` I get zero categories or, if I change the `parentField` to 0 I get all categories in one single branch and a huge mess (since names overlapp).

Comment: @DainisAbols you can compare your TCA with TCA form [tt_news 7.6.3](https://github.com/rupertgermann/tt_news/blob/7.6.3/Configuration/TCA/tt_news.php#L339-L361). Probably, the issue can be solved by adding `'parentField' => 'parent_category',` in `treeConfig` section.

Comment: Thank you, `parent_category` seems promising on first tests, will let you know tomorrow morning. For now workday is already 2h overdue.

Comment: @DainisAbols nice, I've updated my code example in the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: I took the new TCA from `tt_news` repository. Now I get the tree correct, but it doesn't read the old selects (the new ones work fine). I see that the new TCA also uses `'dataProvider' => \WMDB\TtNews\Tree\TableConfiguration\NewsDatabaseTreeDataProvider::class,` what I don't have. Any ideas about that one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145628/discussion-between-viktor-livakivskyi-and-dainis-abols).